# Replication with no network connectivity

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, data-synchronization

I have SQL Servers on two isolated networks that cannot be connected directly. However, there is a need to keep data in sync between the two systems. Obviously SQL Server replication won't work. It might however be possible to transfer files from one network to the other. So - I am soliciting for any and all ideas to keep the two databases in sync without using replication, and without incurring any major downtime for restores and such, since both databases will be in nearly constant use (ruling out log shipping).

Comment: Can the servers on the two isolated networks be periodically connected to eachother?

Comment: Craig - no, they cannot.

Comment: Another option - are there any DBMS's (Oracle, MySQL, etc.) that might be able to accomplish this?